# How can I initialize the schema in Sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I create the schema (tables) **by an sql script** in Sqlite3? I know I can do that via sqlitebrowser, but what if I want a user on a different computer just to run my db_schema.sql to create all the tables before it run an application working with the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949230/how-can-i-create-a-new-sqlite-file-and-table-at-runtime-using-fielddefs

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database file and initialize the schema with a single command from a command prompt by redirecting the input to your script file like this:

sqlite3 my_database.db < db_schema.sql

https://sqlite.org/cli.html